# Why is this JavaScript working in Firefox but not other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have a simple script that works (or should) on page load and sorts a dynamically created list by the list items' Ids. It works fine in Firefox on both Windows and iPad Firefox but not on other browsers, including Chrome, Edge, my Android phone's browser or Amazon's Silk. I thought it might be something to do with my website so I put the code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Scrabble96/pen/GRyLLBB) and the issue is exactly the same there, too.

When I inspect the code in Chrome and Edge no errors are reported, so the code is just being ignored. Why?

Here is a slightly simplified version:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let
    list = document.querySelector('.list'),
    results = document.querySelectorAll('.sort');
  let sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(results, 0);
  sliced.sort(sortByElementId());
  sliced.reduce(function(list, item) {
      list.appendChild(item);
      return list;
    },
    list);

  function sortByElementId() {
    return function(a, b) {
      b.id;
      a.id;
      return a.id > b.id;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="day-or-evening">
  <h4>Meeting</h4>
  <ul id="meetings" class="list">
    <li id="id-22" class="sort li-22">Tuesday afternoon</li>
    <li id="id-23" class="sort li-23">Tuesday evening</li>
    <li id="id-25" class="sort li-25">Wednesday evening</li>
    <li id="id-24" class="sort li-24">Wednesday morning</li>
    <li id="id-27" class="sort li-27">Thursday evening</li>
    <li id="id-17" class="sort li-17">Monday afternoon</li>
    <li id="id-26" class="sort li-26">Thursday afternoon</li>
    <li id="id-21" class="sort li-21">Monday evening</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a lot of issues here: 1. why are you wrapping your sorting function in an extra function? 2. Why are you needlessly adding `a.id;` and `b.id;`? 3. Why are you using reduce just for a side-effect? And that's just what I can see from glancing at the code. Highly recommend using an editor that will warn you about mistakes like this like vscode or something (or adding plugins to whatever you're using now to get the same effect).

Comment: 1. I based this code on someone else's that I found here as my JS is not good enough to work it out for myself. It seemed to work how I wanted after a few tweaks so I used it. 2. I thought I needed to specify that I wanted the items to be sorted by their Ids and not their values, i.e. not alphabetical order by the innerHTML. 3. No idea what the 'reduce' was for so I left it. As I said, I tested it in Codepen.io which usually flags up errors but I will do so in VSCode.

Comment: Codepen is going to tell you if the code has full-blown errors, but a good linter (and vscode has one built in) will a lot of times tell you when you are doing things that are unnecessary or sub-optimal. This is especially key if you don't have great JS skills yourself yet. Use the tools.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith. Mind you, it seems I'm on the wrong track anyway, trying to sort alphanumeric elements with a numeric sorting tool. I'm struggling to find how to pull the list elements from the page as an array - without typing them out manually into the JS - so I can then use something like ```list.sort()```. All the examples I've seen just sort static lists and return them as innerHTML into a parent element.

Comment: Yes I understand that does not solve your actual problem, which is why I left it as a comment rather than an answer. But more code means more bugs, and unnecessary and unidiomatic statements make the code not only more likely to be buggy but also harder to read, understand, fix, get help with on Stack Overflow, etc.

Comment: I think I've found a solution. Some very old code (from 2012) which I again borrowed and adapted from another question on here, but it seems to work on all browsers. However, I wouldn't be at all surprised if you pull it to pieces. Here it is on my https://codepen.io/Scrabble96/pen/QWaPROE. I put both new and old version is VSCode and no problems were found on either. Hm.

Answer (score 1):

Your sort comparator function is invalid. A sort comparator must return (for arguments `a` and `b`) one of:

- a negative number, if `a` should go before `b` in the result;
- a positive number, if `b` should go before `a`;
- zero, if `a` and `b` are already in order.

If you don't do that, you can get inconsistent and incorrect sorting results. There is no guarantee that for any two elements in your array, for example, that they'll always be passed as `a` and `b` (instead of `b` and `a`).

For sorting arrays of numbers, subtracting one from the other results in a good return value. For strings, as in your case, you can use the `.localeCompare()` function of strings, though that has some possibly odd behavior in some special cases.

Comment: Probably worth noting that lots of crappy tutorials/examples use the greater than comparison for sorting numbers, so not entirely the OPs fault.

Comment: @JaredSmith yes, and it'll *sometimes* work, depending on the data and the sort implementation. It's so easy to do it correctly too.

Comment: @JaredSmith also I may have gotten it backwards, lol *e*: no it's fine

Comment: Oh. So it doesn't - or shouldn't - sort alphabetically, then, only numerically? When originally searching for clues on how to sort alphabetically I don't think I ever came across ```.localeCompare```

Comment: @Gillian it's not necessarily what `a.localeCompare(b)` was designed to do, at least not specifically, but it (almost always) works fine. The "weird" cases are usually with unexpected effects of other character sets, but because you're sorting element id values they're probably not unusual strings.

Comment: `zero, if a and b are already in order` not quite

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy. I'll look into that method